# Does SQL Server Express SSRS support using custom assemblies as a datasource?

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-express

I am trying to find out if SQL Server express SSRS supports using custom assemblies as a datasource. My assumption is no but I would like a concrete answer.

Based on this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020.aspx it seems like my assumption is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it has been long enough... I tried and couldn't get it to work. Could have been me but it doesn't appear to work. Express limits a lot of features...